# Can't use pouchdb with Typescript ? Types problem?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, pouchdb, definitelytyped

I am trying to install pouchdb in a typescript (ionic) application. The types don't work

```
npm install --save pouchdb
npm install --save-dev @types/pouchdb
```

When I try to use it (import Pouchdb from 'pouchdb'), I get this error

> ERROR in src/app/services/pouchdb.service.ts(3,8): error TS1192: Module '"C:/Users/User/PROG/toto/node_modules/@types/pouchdb/index"' has no default export.

I tried

```
import * as Pouchdb from 'pouchdb'
```

The error disappears here, but appears after, I still can't use the pouchdb functions.

Is there a solution?

Comment: PouchDB has an [export assignment](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/59dc9899d3670ca4cd702fc64cad0fb58bc601cd/types/pouchdb/index.d.ts#L23) (`export = ...`), so you need to enable the `esModuleInterop` compiler option if you want `import PouchDB from 'pouchdb'` to work.  If `esModuleInterop` is disabled, then the second approach should have worked (although `import Pouchdb = require('pouchdb')` would be better practice); if you'd like help with it, please post the exact error you got and the code it occurred in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const PouchDB = require('pouchdb').default;
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

Have you seen this? https://pouchdb.com/guides/setup-pouchdb.html#typescript

In `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
  }
}
```

Then in TypeScript:

```
import PouchDB from 'pouchdb';
```

Answer (score 0):

I also am using Ionic 4, PouchDB and pouchdb-find. The following worked for me:

> npm install pouchdb @types/pouchdb
>
> npm install pouchdb-find @types/pouchdb-find

In tsconfig.json I added the following:

```
{
  {
    "compilerOptions": {
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
  }
}
```

Then in the provider where I'm using pouchdb and pouchdb-find, I put the following 2 lines:

```
const PouchDB = require('pouchdb');
PouchDB.plugin(require('pouchdb-find'));
```